# PsExec v 1.98 Output Redirection Issue

Tags: c#, psexec

I dont think any of the previous questions on this topic gave an answer for this issue. I use psexec to execute a remote exe file . I am getting the output of the exe file when i run it in command line. `psexec.exe \\machine C:\somename.exe`.
When i use C sharp Process Execution it either hangs or it doesnt redirect the output. For some exe's it timesout and for some Redirected standard Output is empty and Error contains Exe exited with code 0. Is there any way to capture the output ?

```
 ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName =GetPsExecPath();
        startInfo.Arguments = arguments;
        Debug.WriteLine(arguments);
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
        error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        Debug.WriteLine(error);
        Debug.WriteLine(output);
        process.close();
```

Edit: Soln
So the issue is primarily cause Psexec throws a lot of other things into the stderr and hence the order in which we read them, whtever it may be leads to deadlock if we use ReadToEnd(). So if we use BeginOutputReadLine it works like a charm!

Comment: Show us the Code you use to execute psexec.

Comment: also if i dont redirect output and error it executes and exits with code 0. only whn i redirect it causes these pblms.

Comment: and when you run it via the command line, it returns data? using the same arguments you pass in your program?

Comment: ya it does.. The exe actually prints a line and it does get printed in the command line.

Comment: ok, can you please edit your question... thanks now we know its about certain EXE's that timesout &/or dont return StdError message. Maybe you need to use Netmon/WireShark with Process Monitor to compare timesout vs no-output and fix the timing out first.

Comment: the actual pblm is for the exes which returns the stderror, stdoutput is empty which shldnt be cause in command line it prints the output but when redirected thro c sharp process it is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code snippet has very high odds for causing deadlock.  Because you first read StandardError, then StandardOutput.  Which means that process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() isn't going to get called until the process exits.  Which means that psexec won't be able to flush its stdout output buffer when it fills up with enough characters.  Which means that it will block and thus never terminate.  Deadlock city.

You'll have much better odds if you swap the two calls, most programs send the bulk of output to stdout.  However with still non-zero odds for deadlock if psexec writes a lot of characters to stderr for some reason.  You eliminate that entirely by using BeginOutputReadLine and BeginErrorReadLine instead.